# How should I go about declaring a religious article?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, religion

During my current trip abroad, I was given a gold coin from my parents’ Taoist master (whom I do not believe is an ordained minister), which has been marked with red ink and sealed in a ziplock pouch. The coin, as I’ve been told, is supposed to be of religious significance in Taoism, but I am unsure as to what value I should assign to it, or whether my gold coin even qualifies as a religious article under [Memorandum D10-15-12](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/publications/dm-md/d10/d10-15-12-eng.html).

Regardless: Do I need to declare my gold coin, and if so, what dollar value should I assign it (or rather, how can I go about estimating it?). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @NeanDerThal A conservative approach is presented by [this Canada Customs page](https://travel.gc.ca/returning/customs/declare), which starts with the  assertion **Be sure . . . declare everything** (boldface in original). A traveler cannot, I think, be in error by doing this.

Comment: Be careful not to run into trouble *exporting* an artifact.

Comment: is it really gold? just in itself that's rather valuable.

Comment: Is it really a gold *coin* or is it a *charm*, the latter more likely to be made of gold plated base metal, with little or no inherent value?

Answer (score 5):

> Regardless: Do I need to declare my gold coin,

yes

> and if so, what dollar value should I assign it

at least the value of gold per grams which in itself will be significant -- a quarter troy oz bullion gold coin is about the same size as a Canadian 5c coin (20mm diameter , 1.78mm thickness vs 21.2mm, 1.76mm thickness) and at the time of this writing is worth 432.6 CAD. Of course bullion is near 100% gold and I can't know how much gold is in your coin.

> whether my gold coin even qualifies as a religious article under Memorandum D10-15-12.

Read the following:

> 15. The importer may be asked to provide a certification attesting that articles claimed under the tariff item are in fact for religious devotion. The certificate must:

> (a) be from an appropriate religious administration (e.g. Catholic or Anglican Diocese, Jewish Synagogue, Hindu Temple, Moslem Mosque) that has charitable status from the Canada Revenue Agency;

[Searching the CRA](https://apps.cra-arc.gc.ca/ebci/hacc/srch/pub/dsplyBscSrch) for taoist lists six such. Contact one and ask whether they would be willing to issue an official declaration. I strongly suspect the answer will be no.

Comment: +1. Also note that  Memorandum D10-15-12 says that anything not *explicitly* listed does not qualify as a religious article. Coins are not included.